# Append using Regex Replace with repeating pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, regexp-replace

I have following pattern which I need to append/replace in my Java program.

*Example string:*

```
1: {\"values" : ["AnyValue1", "TestValue", "Dummy", "SomeValue"], "key" : "value"}

2: {\"otherValue\": \"AnyValue1\", \n" + "\"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\"}
```

There can be `N` number of values in this value array.

I need to append all values with `_val`. However, *only the values inside `values` should be appended with `_val`*.

```
Output 1: { "values" : ["AnyValue1_val", "TestValue_val", "Dummy_val", "SomeValue_val"], "key" : "value" }

Output 2: {"otherValue": "AnyValue1", 
          "values" : ["AnyValue1_val", "TestValue_val", "Dummy_val", "SomeValue_val"], "key" : "value"}
```

I was wondering if somehow I can use regex Replace instead of going through loops?

Content are in a String:

```
String content = "{ \"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\" }";
```

Comment: The answer depends to how you are storing the information. Regex can be applied to `strings` or `texts`. *If you have a string or some text* = `{ "values" : ["AnyValue1", "TestValue", "Dummy", "SomeValue"], "key" : "value" }` then you can apply regex to it. However, if the values are stored in an array, then you need to extract the value first before any operation on them.

Comment: This is stored as String:
        String content = "{ \"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\" }";

Comment: I will be working on a solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "{ \"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\" }";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\[)(.*?)(\\].*)").matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        String val = matcher.group(2).replaceAll("(\\w+)", "$1_val");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + val + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ "values" : ["AnyValue1_val", "TestValue_val", "Dummy_val", "SomeValue_val"], "key" : "value" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on your problem for some minutes now. I have come up with an solution. It might not be the best since I am not that much used to using regex.

---

### Concept

*It is a two step solution:*

```
1st step: Obtain the substring between [...] using regex.
2nd step: Obtain all the substring between "..." and append "_val" in the end.
```

The reason why we need to obtain the substring between [...] first is due to the fact that if we apply 2nd step straight away, then "values", "key" and "value" will also be changed. It is not something you wanted.

---

### Code

```
//Set the string
String str = "{\"otherValue\": \"AnyValue1\", \n" + "\"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\"}";

//Set the first pattern to find the substring between [...]
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).*(?=])");
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(str);

//To locate part of string not to replace
int startIndex;
int endIndex;

if (matcher1.find())
{
    String values = matcher1.group();
    startIndex = matcher1.start();
    endIndex = matcher1.end();
     
    //Set the first pattern to find all the substring between "..."
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\")[a-zA-z0-9]+(?=\")");
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(values);

    while (matcher2.find())
    {
        values = values.replace(matcher2.group(), matcher2.group()+"_val");
    }

    System.out.println(str.substring(0, startIndex) + values + str.substring(endIndex));
}
```

---

### Output

```
{"otherValue": "AnyValue1", 
"values" : ["AnyValue1_val", "TestValue_val", "Dummy_val", "SomeValue_val"], "key" : "value"}
```

---

I hope I have helped you. There might exist better methods in the `java.util.regex.Pattern` or `java.util.regex.Matcher` class which might do things in an easier way. Maybe they can replace all the substrings in a single command. However, I do not use these classes a lot so I am not familiar with it.

Do comment if you any doubts in the regex used.

PS: *If anyone finds any improvement in my answer, especially if it can be made simpler, do mention it. I find my current answer a bit complicated. I think it can be improved.*

Comment: Your replace is replacing if same name found in other parts of string. while @saka1029 solution does correctly but it is using lambda and my actual project is on older version which doesn't support this syntax.

Comment: @Faisal *It is replacing any string which is a combination of characters a-z,A-Z or 0-9*. What problem are you facing? Are all values not getting appended with `_val`? If that is the problem, I think I will be able to help if you can tell me *how can any value be named*?

Comment: thanks for your help though... Following was the case which was not working but I have done with slightly different way.

            String str = "{ \"otherValue\": \"AnyValue1\", \n" +
                    "\"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\" }";

It was also changing: "otherValue": "AnyValue1_val, while this is not part of "values"

Comment: @Faisal I have edited my answer. It should work now. I did test it against the input you gave. *Do comment if you face any other problems. I hope someone else answers your question though*. I find my answer quite complicated. *I think a much simpler to your problem might exist*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String content = "{ \"values\" : [\"AnyValue1\", \"TestValue\", \"Dummy\", \"SomeValue\"], \"key\" : \"value\" }";
Pattern bracket = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
Pattern string = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
String result =  bracket.matcher(content)
    .replaceAll(m -> string.matcher(m.group())
        .replaceAll(n -> "\"" + n.group(1) + "_val\""));
System.out.println(result);
```

output:

```
{ "values" : ["AnyValue1_val", "TestValue_val", "Dummy_val", "SomeValue_val"], "key" : "value" }
```